# Pure JSON? Error: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my error:

```
07-05 23:27:47.883: E/log_tag(2657): connection success 
07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): Error parsing data <br />
07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>

07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\sample\insertOrders.php on line <i>23</i></th></tr>
07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>245224</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\sample\insertOrders.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\insertOrders.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): </table></font>
07-05 23:27:47.890: E/log_tag(2657): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is my PHP code

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot   connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($con,$db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
//initial query
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (TableNum, MenuID) VALUES (:table, :menuid) ";

//Update query
$query_params = array(
    ':table' => $_POST['TableNum'],
    ':menuid' => $_POST['MenuID']
);

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db_name->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add post!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    die(json_encode($response));}
```

I've read a lot about this error. I'm parsing an HTML block, not pure JSON. I really can't define what really is a pure JSON so I need someone to pin-point it to me with the PHP code that I have.

Comment: [This is json.](http://json.org/) You're parsing HTML.

Comment: ^ That's not the real cause. You have a database error rendered in HTML - so fix the error. Hmm, should `$db_name` in the `prepare()` call be `$con`? I imagine the database name is a string, not an object.

Comment: You should post more of your php code. The error message states that you call `prepare` on a non-object in line 23 of `insertOrders.php`. The errormessage seems to be added to your `$response` and therefore `json_encode` does not work

Comment: (There is not enough error checking here anyway - make it more robust by checking object validity prior to using them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real error is that this line:

```
$stmt   = $db_name->prepare($query);
```

should be:

```
$stmt   = $con->prepare($query);
```

`$db_name` is just a string while `$con` is your actual mysqli connection which you can use to prepare queries. The json error is just wrapped around the actual exception that's being thrown and displayed by xdebug.

Comment: @LevLevinstine: it is usual to show what code actually _is_ on the line you specify. In this case it looks like the new problem is on your `execute()` line, which means your `prepare()` failed. Check your query.

Comment: @halfer  $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

Comment: $con->prepare will return ```FALSE``` if there is an error, which is probably what's happening. Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to figure out what the error is on your query. ```if (!$stmt) { echo $con->error; }```

Answer (score 0):

Json is a data interchange format. You can read more about it here [www.json.org](http://www.json.org)

Your php code returned error in html, json parser was not handle it. Json parser (n matter what you will use) won't handle it.

```
jsfiddle.net/chzx0hw2/
```

Here is a preview what was returned.

Answer (score 0):

can you try not to place the json_encode() within die()?

back in the day, when i parse array to json, i use this kind of format

```
$array = array("flag" => 0, "response" => "success");
    json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I already fixed my error. Ill just take note of this. Thanks!